# javascript implementation of encryption including plausible deniability

Tags: javascript

Is there any javascript implementation of encryption including plausible deniability?

I want something exhibiting the features described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deniable_encryption

Deniable encryption allows the sender of an encrypted message to deny sending that message. This requires a trusted third party. A possible scenario works like this:

1. Alice is the wife of Bob, who suspects his wife is engaged in adultery. She wants to communicate with her secret lover Carl. She creates two keys, one intended to be kept secret, the other intended to be sacrificed. She passes the secret key (or both) to Carl.
2. Alice constructs an innocuous message M1 for Carl (intended to be revealed to Bob in case of discovery) and an incriminating love letter M2 to Carl. She constructs a cipher-text C out of both messages M1, M2 and emails it to Carl.
3. Carl uses his key to decrypt M2 (and possibly M1, in order to read the fake message too).
4. Bob finds out about the email to Carl, becomes suspicious and forces Alice to decrypt the message.
5. Alice uses the sacrificial key and reveals the innocuous message M1 to Bob. Since Bob does not know the other key, he has to assume that there is no other message M2.

Comment: This probably belongs in: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Diodeus, [or maybe not](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1624/are-im-looking-for-x-questions-on-topic).

Comment: What exactly is your use-case?

Comment: I want to create a self contained html document to sit on a flash drive, with encrypted data embedded. I want it to open one set of data with a password, and have a secret part in the encrypted data, plausibly deniable, that contains another set of secret data. I would like the html file to be able to generate a clone of itself, with updated data - so be able to create the hidden section within an encrypted block.

Comment: Hey, thanks for re-opening this question. I always believed it was valid. Why all the sudden interest?

Comment: Since I asked this, I have been working on an app, using titanium mobile and nodejs on the server side (so all javascript), which uses both AES and RSA (all implemented in javascript), including generating RSA keys. Although it has not come up yet, I see plausible deniability as the ultimate crypto security. It would be nice to see a javascipt option.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of Javascript libraries that provide cryptographic primitives, but i've never heard of any that includes plausible deniability.

You could implement an encryption scheme similar to the one used by TrueCrypt. It's limited to only 2 sets of encrypted data: the decoy data and truly secret data. But it's design is pretty simple, so if you don't need more than 2 sets of data - go for it. You could modify it to allow more than 2 sets, but it can't be 'dynamic'.

It is explained in detail on [TrueCrypt documentation page](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/volume-format-specification#Y360), but the basic principle is that encrypted data contains fixed-width headers for each data set. Header includes info about its data set. In most basic scenario that would be only offset of the start of data set in the whole encrypted block, length of that data set and some canary value used to check if the header is successfully decrypted. When user provides a password the system tries to decrypt 1st header, if it fails it tries with next header, until it succeeds or there are no headers left. If it succeeds, then it decrypt bytes specified in the header.

This scheme was designed for file system encryption, so it would have a big flaw when used in your system - when adversary forces you to reveal key to the decoy data, he will ask why is its size smaller than the size of whole encrypted block.

Answer (score -1):

Interesting question.  There are Javascript cryptographic libraries out there [here](http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) but your use case does not require you to implement this in Javascript, and you'd probably be better off using a different language.

Why?  Deniable encryption is a form of security that *requires* security by obscurity, by definition, so implementing it using a scripting language probably isn't the best way to go about it (anybody and everybody can see your implementation details).  Write it in a strong, computationally-powerful language and lock it away on a server somewhere.

Comment: Deniable encryption should not require obscure algorithm, with both the data, and algorithm, the attacker should still not be able to know if there is a second/third/fourth super secret message hidden in there.

Comment: I don't mean obscure algorithm, I mean obscure architecture.